# RailsのWebアプリをRenderにデプロイしようとしたら、Build failedしました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsチュートリアルの第6章に取り組み、最後にRenderにデプロイ(Deploy latest commitボタンを押す)をしたところ、上手く行かずBuild failedしてしまいました。以下がエラーメッセージ部分と思われるログの一部です。

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server at "10.211.236.24", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server at "10.211.236.24", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

ログを確認してググったところ、データベースが起動していないことが要因かもしれないと思い確認してみましたが、データベースをRestartしても結果は変わらずでした。(データベースは、同じくRenderにてPostgreSQLで作成しています)
また、Tasks: TOP => db:migrateとログにあったので実行してみましたが、何も起こらずに結果は変わりませんでした。

herokuではなくRenderでのデプロイ失敗に関する情報が少なくて困っています。この問題を解決して、デプロイを成功させたいです。ちなみに、一つ前の第5章の最後で行ったデプロイは問題なく成功しました。

Answer (score 0):

render上のPostgreSQLに既にusersというテーブルが存在しています。第二章のtoy_appで作りました。よってコンフリクトしています。
なので、PostgreSQLを作り直すか、以下の記事を参考にテーブルを削除してください。

たぶん質問者はもう見てないですが、私みたいにこの解答を見つけた人がハッピーになれると信じて。

[Renderによるデプロイ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Naaa0/items/8e2ad76e40e3a638ddfc)